# Track speed of Mouse?

Tags: mouse

I am creating an app that makes it so that when you move your mouse really fast, the mouse gets bigger for a second. This is a behavior I was used to when I used Mac a long time ago.

I need a way to track the speed/acceleration of the mouse in the terminal so I can see when to make the mouse get bigger.

I am looking for a terminal command that can track the speed of the mouse cursor.

Comment: If you can get the location of the pointer, you could check it, say, ten times per second, and store the 50 most recent results in an array. From there, a bit of math would let you calculate the speed.